# Extract emails from a web page in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have found the following code that crawls a website (I think all the website) for emails

```
import re
import requests
import requests.exceptions
from urllib.parse import urlsplit
from collections import deque
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# starting url. replace google with your own url.
starting_url = 'http://www.miet.ac.in'

# a queue of urls to be crawled
unprocessed_urls = deque([starting_url])

# set of already crawled urls for email
processed_urls = set()

# a set of fetched emails
emails = set()

# process urls one by one from unprocessed_url queue until queue is empty
while len(unprocessed_urls):

    # move next url from the queue to the set of processed urls
    url = unprocessed_urls.popleft()
    processed_urls.add(url)

    # extract base url to resolve relative links
    parts = urlsplit(url)
    base_url = "{0.scheme}://{0.netloc}".format(parts)
    path = url[:url.rfind('/')+1] if '/' in parts.path else url

    # get url's content
    print("Crawling URL %s" % url)
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
    except (requests.exceptions.MissingSchema, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError):
        # ignore pages with errors and continue with next url
        continue

    # extract all email addresses and add them into the resulting set
    # You may edit the regular expression as per your requirement
    new_emails = set(re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", response.text, re.I))
    emails.update(new_emails)
    print(emails)
    # create a beutiful soup for the html document
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    # Once this document is parsed and processed, now find and process all the anchors i.e. linked urls in this document
    for anchor in soup.find_all("a"):
        # extract link url from the anchor
        link = anchor.attrs["href"] if "href" in anchor.attrs else ''
        # resolve relative links (starting with /)
        if link.startswith('/'):
            link = base_url + link
        elif not link.startswith('http'):
            link = path + link
        # add the new url to the queue if it was not in unprocessed list nor in processed list yet
        if not link in unprocessed_urls and not link in processed_urls:
            unprocessed_urls.append(link)
```

How can I modify such a code to extract only one web page ..? I just need to target one web page not the whole website.

Comment: your question isn't clear or limited to specific issue, kindly check [ask] and edit your question with the exact issue

Comment: The question for getting emails from a web site (not all the websites but just one link)

Comment: remove the loop seems simple. Thought to be honest.... much easier to not bother with a queue then and simply pull out the bs4 bit and make a single request.

Comment: @QHarr I am so newbie at python stuff :)

Comment: @QHarr Can you help me .. the website will have a JavaScript and the code doesn't deal with it? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just delete all lines beginning from `for anchor in soup.find_all("a"):`. Your document should look like this then:

```
import re
import requests
import requests.exceptions
from urllib.parse import urlsplit
from collections import deque
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# starting url. replace google with your own url.
starting_url = 'http://www.miet.ac.in'

# a queue of urls to be crawled
unprocessed_urls = deque([starting_url])

# set of already crawled urls for email
processed_urls = set()

# a set of fetched emails
emails = set()

# process urls one by one from unprocessed_url queue until queue is empty
while len(unprocessed_urls):

    # move next url from the queue to the set of processed urls
    url = unprocessed_urls.popleft()
    processed_urls.add(url)

    # extract base url to resolve relative links
    parts = urlsplit(url)
    base_url = "{0.scheme}://{0.netloc}".format(parts)
    path = url[:url.rfind('/')+1] if '/' in parts.path else url

    # get url's content
    print("Crawling URL %s" % url)
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
    except (requests.exceptions.MissingSchema, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError):
        # ignore pages with errors and continue with next url
        continue

    # extract all email addresses and add them into the resulting set
    # You may edit the regular expression as per your requirement
    new_emails = set(re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", response.text, re.I))
    emails.update(new_emails)
    print(emails)
    # create a beutiful soup for the html document
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
```

To generate random email-addresses with Python use this:

```
from faker import Faker

faker = Faker()

for i in range(12):
    print(f'{faker.email()}')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's wonderful. But when trying with this site `https://www.randomlists.com/email-addresses`, it doesn't work.

Comment: This is because this website loads the email-addresses with javascript after the site has loaded. So when crawling the webpage, the addresses aren't in the page yet and the crawler can't find them. You can use my other answer to generate random email-addresses with Python.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any luck to deal with JavaScript ..? as the target is to get the emails from any page that has or hasn't JavaScript.